# html id selectors vs other kinds of selectors

Tags: html, css, dom, selector

I heard that id selectors are unique in that there can only be one element with a certain ID name on a page. In practice this does not seem to be true at all when selecting elements by their id in javascript and css, neither the libraries or the browsers seem to care, are there any remaining consequences of having multiple elements with the same id, such as a browser that is much more strict about this and won't load a page if there are elements with the same id?

I would be content if the saying simply wasn't true that "elements must have unique ids"

Comment: "In practice this does not seem to be true at all" What do you mean by this?

Comment: @j08691 none of my browsers seem to care that elements have the same id.

Comment: Technically, most modern browsers can render even the most horrifyingly malformed html, but cross-browser compatibility and desired results will suffer greatly.

Comment: HTML is a markup language. Not programming language. All errors are suppressed and the document will still be rendered.

Comment: @BradM technically referring internet explorer?

Comment: Consequences I think are different between browsers, for example, some browser will apply CSS styles on the first element that has that ID, some will apply them on the last, same in JavaScript, I don't think there's a rule for this, I think its different between browsers.

Comment: Just because a browser may be forgiving, doesn't mean you should ignore the correct coding standards.

Comment: @DreamEater yes, but I'm referring to modifying selectors with javascript and css. there still seems to be no consequences

Comment: @j08691 nobody has even confirmed to me that unique ID selectors are the more correct coding standard

Comment: What do you mean by correct coding standard? Read this http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: ITT, this might be [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1983834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will all render (to varying degrees) but the consequences are apparent when you use CSS of JS to select on the ID. In that case it may not give you the one you are trying to select. It is undetermined which will get selected and may not be repeatable.

Comment: okay, so it is unlike selecting by classes where all elements tied to a class will get modified? when selecting by id only one element should be expected to be modified?

Comment: Correct. Classes grab all, ID is supposed to occur only once.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple elements with same id, changing a css property will only affect first element.

```
 <div id="test"></div>
 <div id="test"></div>

 $("#test").css("border-color","red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/tLB4U/

Comment: more specifically, jquery only affects first element